# table-responsive in bootstrap 4 doesn't work

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

i'm beginner who just started

i've tried to following video of creating forum using bootstrap 4 in [youtube](https://youtu.be/4_YQ6efCyW8)

but table-responsive doesn't work

i think my code is same as in video but browser not the same

[my broswer](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15TtURhBr6zzY1B0u020NsE_qu3WqtZsu)

[browser in youtube](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mCoi3X1Oa1oBvDti9l4xNXFcV5LqAenp)

here's my table. i hope someone help me..

thanks

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="forum-col">Forum</th>
            <th scope="col">Topics</th>
            <th scope="col">Posts</th>
            <th scope="col" class="last-post-col">Last post</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h3 class="h5"><a href="#0">Forum name</a></h3>
                <p>ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>5</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>18</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h4 class="h6"><a href="#0">Post name</a></h4>
                <div>by <a href="#0">Author name</a></div>
                <div>05 Apr 2017, 20:07</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
     <tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first TD is not set to word wrap.  You can add the following CSS declaration to your TD elements to resolve this issue:

```
word-break:break-all;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should wrap the table in  element and take the .table-responsive class out of  tag and put that class in wrapping div element. .table-responsive class should include break point size for example .table-responsive-sm

```
<div class="table-responsive-sm">

  <table class="table table-dark table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>.</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the td content length is so high. You need to break the words inorder to get responsive table

Look at this Fiddle [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pradeep0594/xrpuhfqw/1/)

CSS:

```
td{
  word-break:break-all;
}
```